# Python Writing 'N' bytes data to Binary file

Tags: python, excel, struct, binary

I have following data in Excel sheet, 
1st column is number of bytes, 2nd column is its data (dat is in decimal,hex,ip address format)

Question is how to write these into binary file, like 
 in 1 bytes data,write 0x01,then 2 bytes data, write 0xAABB,then 
 in 4 bytes data,write 10080000(dec)..etc even ip address in 4 bytes,write 
10.65.84.8

**Questions:**
**1)is it required to convert all data to one format (ie decimal or hex) ?
2) are there inbuilt functions which gives write(num_of_bytes, value) ?**

File.xls

### Number of bytes   Data

```
1             0x01 (hex)
2             0xAABB
4             10080000
2             100
4             18181818 (decimal)
4             10.65.84.8(ip address)
```

i am new to python and have done following to read data from Excel(cvs) sheet

```
def open_file():
    book = xlrd.open_workbook('file.csv') 
    # get the first worksheet
    first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

    # read a cell
    cell = first_sheet.cell(0,0)
    num_rows = first_sheet.nrows 
    num_cols = first_sheet.ncols 

    for m in range(0, num_rows):
        for n in range(0, num_cols):
            cell = first_sheet.cell(m,n)
            print 'cell value %d',cell.value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html), pack and unpack to read and write binary data, the best solution I found and the cleanest is to handle data in hex() format. Also pay attention to the indianness of your machine, when you will write and read, is it on the same machine!

Cheers,